# Problems with FB.api

Tags: javascript, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I wrote the following code but for some reason the **FB.api** is not working. I can say that because there are no log messages in javascript console. I have already authenticated the user and have taken the publish_stream permission.The below code is inside the **FB.login** block (I hope this isnt a problem).I have used **jQuery** as I already knew how to make the **get** request using it.

```
jQuery.ajax( {
    url: access,
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function (resp) { 
    var data_item='This is a successful post plz do not comment this is a test';
    FB.api('me/feed', 'post', {message: data_item}, function(response) {
    if (!response || response.error) {
        console.log('Error occured');
    } else {
        console.log('Post ID: ' + response.id);
    }
});
```

Any help or suggestions **?**

Answer (score 0):

You need to specify the acess token, i had the same problem.. I just add the acess token and problem solved..

Take a look here: http://www.friendouh.com/

```
    jQuery.ajax( {
        url: access,
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function (resp) { 
        var data_item='This is a successful post plz do not comment this is a test';
        FB.api('me/feed', 'post', {message: data_item,access_token: 'your_acess_token'}, function(response) {
        if (!response || response.error) {
            console.log('Error occured');
        } else {
            console.log('Post ID: ' + response.id);
        }
    });
```

Comment: when you o FB.login, in the response will contain the access token, store it somewhere and call it when ever you need to use it

Comment: i did that but it still doesnt work if you want i can give the whole code